# How can I place a ProgressBar at the right of the Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-toolbar

With the new Lollipop API, we have to use a Toolbar if we want to personalize the action bar aspect.

Adding a ProgressBar to the Toolbar is as simple as adding it to the Toolbar ViewGroup, [as Chris Banes said](https://plus.google.com/103829716466878605055/posts/ZqVBYudxvFv).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/material_green_500"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <!-- Color is Brown 500 -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTint="#795548"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But how can we place it at the right of the Toolbar, where it belongs?

The `layout_gravity` attribute seems to not be defined for the Toolbar. Setting it from the xml has no effect.
I tried to change the width of the ProgressBar, with no success.

What do I do?

**EDIT**: There is a programmatical solution to this problem, see @mdelolmo reply for that.

Comment: layout_gravity is working fine in appcompat 21.0.2

Comment: Awesome! You should make that an answer.

Comment: I found this page when having the same problem as you.
layout_gravity is indeed the answer. My problem and probably yours is that Android studio autocomplete claims there is no layout_gravity, but if you just type it out yourself it finds it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can try this. It worked for me. Key here is to define `layout_gravity` in the xml: `android:layout_gravity="right"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/material_green_500"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<!-- Color is Brown 500 -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateTint="#795548"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Prefer using `layout_gravity="end"` for Right-To-Left compatibility. However notice this is only available from API 17.

Answer (score 14):

I also hit the same wall, but programmatically it works:

```
    Toolbar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT);
```

In my snippet, I align it to the top, to match the alignment of the menu.

Answer (score -4):

A workaround to create the layout completely in xml would be replacing the toolbar content with your own relative layout. To do that, you need to fake the activity title (and also the navigation icon if you are using one), which is literally nesting the following in your Toolbar block.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateTint="#795548"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that 20sp sans-serif-medium is the font used in lollipop toolbar, you might need to adjust the text view parameters to make it look natural in earlier versions.