# Cant set LayoutParams to Toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm getting wierd exception when trying to set layout parametres to my toolbar.

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

I want to place an inner view at the right of a Toolbar, but since xml `layout_gravity` property isn't working fine (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510000/how-can-i-place-a-progressbar-at-the-right-of-the-toolbar)) I am trying to do it programmatically.

My code looks like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setLayoutParams(new Toolbar.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

If I set an instance of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` as a layout params, toolbar just dissappears.
I would appreciate any help

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is being thrown because your trying to cast the LayoutParams to a Class that they do not inherit from hence the Class Cast Exception. to solve this use the LinearLayout.LayoutParams and instead of

```
 new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT));
```

do

```
// Toolbar height is 56dp as per material design guidelines

new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    56,
    Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific height:

```
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    80,
    Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Or add items to your Toolbar, so it's not empty and `wrap_content` actually has something to wrap.

Comment: After setting specific height like you offered, toolbar dissapears too. And I actually have a TextView inside my Toolbar...

Comment: @Bolein95 your code implies that you hide it yourself: `getSupportActionBar().hide();`.

Comment: sorry but that was unnecessary part of listing. I then show it again a bit later